# How do I get referrer of first document loaded into webbrowser to determine how web-page opened

Tags: javascript

**Background to explain the issue**

I have a Java desktop application that as part of a task creates an HTML report and loads it directly into the user's preferred web browser. This is how it works on a PC or mac.

The Java app can also run in remote mode, in this case the whole interface is in a web browser. The main purpose of this is it can then be installed on a NAS and controlled remotely via PC/iPad etcetera, and everything including the HTML report is loaded from the web server running the application.

The trouble with the application is that Safari on mac doesn't like the HTML files to be loaded directly into the web browser, and this (sometimes) prevents the loading of resources and causes the the HTML report to not be rendered correctly.

The solution is for my application to run a simple web server that always serves the report files so the browser would open `http://local:4567/report1.html` rather than `file://C:/application/reportslocation/report1.html` -- in all cases.

**Cancel Button Problem**

This works but now I have another problem: the report has a *Cancel* button which should not be shown when running in desktop mode, because this is the first page, so it can't be canceled, whereas remote mode takes you to the start page.

What I used to do was to check the currently loaded URL, and if it starts with `file:`, hide the button:

```
if (window.location.protocol == 'file:') {
    document.getElementById('return').style.visibility='hidden'
}
```

But now all files are served via HTTP, so I changed it to

```
if (!document.referrer) {
    document.getElementById('return').style.visibility = 'hidden'
}
```

and it works for the first page of the report because `referrer` is not set when loading from the desktop app.

However there are multiple pages of reports, so when I click on a link to open another page of the report, the Cancel button is now incorrectly displayed because `document.referrer` is no longer empty.

**So my thought was, if I could get the original referrer when opening a page, I could then correctly check if the Cancel button should be displayed.**

Also note, the reports may have been created in desktop mode and then viewed later on in remote mode or vice versa. So the report is only created once and has to be valid for both cases.

Comment: Then you would have to store the "original referrer" somewhere, so that you still have access to it on subsequent pages. Only slight problem with that, neither localStorage nor cookies will work, when you are using the `file` protocol to access this ...

Comment: @CBroe im no longer using file protocol so that is not problem, but could you give example my javascript knowledge is limited.

Comment: Set a cookie when you encounter an empty referrer (that should only be the case when you enter the first initial page from desktop.) And then check if that cookies is set on all pages, and display your button based on that.

Comment: So you only want to display 'Cancel' button from 'remote' mode and only on the first page? Its not exactly clear what 'remote' mode means for report page. But maybe, for 'remote' you could launch page with some parameter an then simply check for it.

Comment: ' display 'Cancel' button from 'remote' mode and only on the first page? ', only for remote i.e basically when previous page, but not only on first page for all pages of the report.

Comment: @CBroe okay I will try the cookie idea, thanks.

Comment: @PaulTaylor to check if there are some previous pages check `History.length`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the http protocol and not the file protocol then I think it would be fine to use the browsers localStoreage.
Such as on the first page:

```
if (!document.referrer) localStorage.setItem('mode', 'desktop')
```

Then on following pages

```
if (localStorage.getItem('mode') === 'desktop') document.getElementById('return').style.visibility='hidden';
```

However if you are using the file protocol then a new store is created for each file, so they won't be transferred/accessible.

Another more hacky option could be to contain this information in your href as a query param if you are in desktop mode or not.

Comment: This nearly worked except  if having opened report from desktop and gone to other pages of report I go back to first page it will then run the code again and because document.referrer not empty this time will now show Cancel. I combinedwith your other idea and this seems to be working, so on first page have        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);const mode = urlParams.get('init');if(mode==='0' || mode==='1') { localStorage.setItem('mode', mode)};if (localStorage.getItem('mode') === '1') document.getElementById('return').style.visibility='hidden';

Comment: and on other pages have if (localStorage.getItem('mode') === '1') document.getElementById('return').style.visibility='hidden';

Comment: Well it's good that it works with a combination of both, however clearly not a clean solution. 
I was wondering if the localStorage could be maintained by clearing the localStorage when the browser is closed using the window.unload function and then doing localStorage.removeItem(mode). However it seems that the window.unload is not recommended due to it not working if the browser is not closed gracefully (via task mgr or on mobile), see mdn.

I guess if you are already maintaining the mode in the href path as a query then do you still need to use the localStorage at all?

Comment: The problem with using the href however is bugs that maybe caused due to link sharing between people that are using desktop/remote

Comment: href is only passed the first time report is opened, the app is a one person app so i think the solution is good enough, even if not perfect.